# CSS Grid: center all content within the grid

Tags: css, grid-layout

My code snippet below works as I wish, but I find no way of centering all `menu__items` when there's more space available.

On smaller screens result is as desired:

[image: small screen example]

On Large screens I get this:

[image: large screen example not desired]

What I want is this:

[image: large screen example desired]

Here's my Code

```css
body {
  background-color: #f5ce42;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.menu__item {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.menu__inner--flex {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(180px, max-content));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu__inner--flex">
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use auto-fit and justify-content :

possible update :

```
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(180px, max-content));
  justify-content:center;
```

Live demo below where item is set to max-width 180px to show centering happening

```css
body {
  background-color: #f5ce42;
  margin:0;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.menu__item {
  max-width: 180px;/* turned dow for demo purpose , 300px is also fine but requires a big screen */
}

.menu__inner--flex {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px; 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(180px, max-content));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  /*  width:100vw;<== this is useless an a pain once a scrollbar shows up, it becomes bigger than the screen, remove it and forget it , idem for width:100% ...*/
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu__inner--flex">
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach looks like the solution, however using `auto-fit` creates un-even column-width when single images have a different aspect ratios. I'll try to fix this with maintaining aspect ratio on the image.

Comment: I can work with your suggested solution, however 2 problems occur. Whenever I have a portrait image, its displayed full-height. Keeping the aspect ratio with the aspect-ratio-padding-top-hack breaks the tesponsiveness of the grid, all images are 180px all the time. Second problem is if an element has no image it gets truncated to min-width. Made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tgu3fy9z/3/

Comment: @browsergarden Is this a possible result : https://jsfiddle.net/6bkr0dum/ (300px turned down to 180px to see centering happening)

Comment: another with text /picture mixed all together : https://jsfiddle.net/6bkr0dum/3/

Comment: my intended behaviour was to maintain the landspace aspect ratio and therefore crop the portrait images. But it breaks the responsiveness of the 'menu__item' like you can see here:  https://jsfiddle.net/v0mqszot/1/

Comment: That's the limits of grid,  js might take over for the img with a portrait ratio. a naive example : https://jsfiddle.net/rzx7wtnk/4/

Answer (score 0):

This two element will set container at center with 75% width

```css
body {
  background-color: #f5ce42;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.menu__item {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.menu__inner--flex {
/* my answer */
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  /* delete width: 100vw; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(180px, max-content));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu__inner--flex">
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you have defined the grid width as 100vw, which will make the grid 100% viewport width, because of which the grid is starting from left to the very end of the screen. For smaller screens it gives you desired result, but for larger viewports all the grid items are placed in the same row.

I would recommend you to reduce the size of the width to somewhere around 60vw-80vw and add `margin: 0 auto` to the grid like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: #f5ce42;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.menu__item {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.menu__inner--flex {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 70vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(180px, max-content));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu__inner--flex">
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
  <a class="menu__item">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree with both answers but I would also then write a media query for smaller screens under lets say 800px putting the width of `.menu__inner--flex` back up to `100vw` so that you get the desired effect of the grid taking over the whole screen as you wanted in the first place.